# unable to run SQL queries in MySQL using phpseclib

Tags: php, mysql, phpseclib

I could successfully connect to the server and login to the MySQL database. But now i need to run few SQL queries on the database tables but facing the error : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I am not sure if the SQL queries are of correct syntax? Also do i need to connect to the server every time i need to run SQL queries? Please provide me with some inputs. Thanks.

```
 /* SUCCESS */
 $ssh = new Net_SSH2('XX.XXX.XX.XXX');
    if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
         exit('Login Failed');
      }

 echo $ssh->exec('pwd');

  /* SUCCESS */
  if (!$ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pDataBaseName \r\n')){
        exit('Login to MySQL Failed');
  }else{
    echo "Login to MySQL Success";
   }

  /* ERROR - facing error in this code*/
   echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pDataBaseName -e "SELECT * FROM cmu_util_all"');
```

Comment: This because you may be entering wrong user name or password.

Comment: Why would you use exec to run MySQL queries?

Comment: @Kyle: He wants the connection between DB server and Web server to be encrypted. SSH is (while unusual) not the worst way to do this.

Comment: Interesting. But wouldn't it do the same thing if you just ran your script  over SSL? And that way you wouldn't have to use exec().

Answer (score 0):

Interesting use of php and mysql (certainly unconventional). There is an easier way: Read up on PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php
About your current login issue:

```
-pDataBaseName
```

should be:

```
-pPassword DataBaseName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT an answer to the question - this has already been given (`-p`). But being too long for a comment let me elaborate on the perofrmance issues:

You connect a new SSH tunnel every time a script runs, this is rather heavy - CPU-wise, but most of all latency-wise.

So I recommend you try the `-L` parameter to SSH and run a system-wide `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 root@...` and then use standard MySQL tools (e.g. PDO) to connect to the already tunneled MySQL at `127.0.0.1`.

Mind tough: You have to use `127.0.0.1`, not `localhost`, as this would try a unix socket connection, which obviously won't work